# Swift, C++ and structs

Tags: c++, swift, struct

I need to send a Swift `struct` consisting of two floats to some C++ code.

#### Swift struct

```
struct ComplexNumber
{
   var real: Float
   var imaginary: Float
}
```

#### C++ method signature

```
void processComplexNumbers(const ComplexNumber *complexNumbers, const int *indices);
```

I have typedef'd the same struct in C++.

When I try to call this from Swift I get the error cannot convert value from `UnsafePointer<ComplexNumber>` to expected argument type `UnsafePointer<ComplexNumber>`. The following code is a simple illustration of this error.

```
var samples = [ComplexNumber]()
var indices = [Int]()
var samplesPtr = UnsafePoiner<ComplexNumber>(samples)
var indices = UnsafePoiner<Int>(indices)
processComplexNumbers(samples, indices)
```

Why can't I get this to work and is there a workaround?

Comment: `sizeofValue(someArray)` gives you the size of `struct Array`, and that is unrelated to the number of elements in the array or the size of the elements itself, compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714086/swift-use-sizeof-with-int32-array. – Some more information would be helpful: How is your struct defined, and what function are you calling?

Comment: You cannot override sizeofValue. And `struct Array` is a fixed-sized struct which contains (opaque) pointers to the actual storage (which may even be non-contiguous). – As I said above, more information is needed to give a concrete answer.

Comment: If the struct contains arrays then transferring the struct alone may not be sufficient because it does not transfer the actual array elements. How to compute the size of the array storage is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714086/swift-use-sizeof-with-int32-array: array.count * sizeof(elementType).

Comment: Pixel is a struct containing an UInt32. Your question is about a struct containing "some arrays". – Sorry, but without *concrete* information, I am out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

#### You can use a C-struct in Swift not vice-versa (Swift 2.1)

I had to define an identical struct called ComplexNumbersF (F is for float) in C that I used for the unsafe pointer call.

```
var samples = [ComplexNumber]()
var samplesPtr = UnsafePoiner<ComplexNumberF>(samples)
```

#### Int isn't int.

If you want to use Swift's `Int` the C++ equivalent is `long`. If you use a C++ `int` every other value will be 0. Alternatively you can use Swift's `Int32`, but that wasn't really desirable in my case.

Comment: is this really an Answer to your original question? if not, I would suggest to edit your question and add this extra part to it. it sounds to me like it's just more information for the initial question.

Comment: @Marius maybe now it is a bit better organized?

Comment: How do you use a c struct in swift? I put one in my bridging header and it is not showing up in Swift.